# nativescript css unit of measurement

Tags: css, nativescript

i have been playing arround with nativescript and i see that it offers us to style elements using css.

However in the docs http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling.html i see nothing mentioned about the unit of measurement for css.

This works

```
.title {
    font-size: 30;
    horizontal-align: center;
    margin: 20;
}
```

And this does not work

```
.title {
    font-size: 30;
    horizontal-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Notice that margin is 20px in the second example.

So my question is when it comes to css what unit does nativescript use?

Answer (score 5):

If someone came across this question in 2019 and beyond, the documentation specifies the units of measurements in Nativescript.

"NativeScript supports **DIPs (Device Independent Pixels)**, **pixels** (via postfix px) and **percentages** (partial support for width, height and margin) as measurement units.

NativeScript's recommended measurement unit is DIP. All measurable properties like width, height, margin, paddings, border-width, etc.) support device independent pixels. The font sizes are always measured in DIPs."

Link: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-measurement-units

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you link to mentions "device-independent units" under the font-size property in the [Supported Properties](http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling.html#supported-properties) section, which suggests that NativeScript does not in fact use any units of measurement per se, and all lengths are expressed in numbers, not dimensions, to emphasize this.

Comment: so if i want to stretch something 100% width or give 50% margin will have to resort to JavaScript to figure out the size then do it am i correct?

Comment: Not sure, the docs are unfortunately extremely vague on this. They mention percentages for some properties but not others. Probably something to do with NativeScript's custom layout system.

Comment: Also check [this doc](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/introducing-resolution---specific-views-for-nativescript) on 'Density-independent pixels (dp)' (scroll down a bit).